# Excel nested IF statements, multiple columns and ranges

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am trying to create a nested IF statement to populate a column in my file with either `G`, `S`, `B` or `Other` but can’t figure out how to when I need to look at data in multiple columns containing multiple values.

I have three different columns that I need to pull together to determine the value of `G`, `S`, `B` or `Other`.  For example, I need to find a way to say IF...

Column A2 >=75% and Column B2 >=10% and Column C2 >=65%, then `G`
Column A2 >=65% but <75% and Column B2>=5% but <10% and Column C2>=55% but <65%, then `S`
Column A2 >=60% but <65% and Column B2>=3% but < 5% and Column C2>=50% but <55%, then `B`,
else `Other`.

Hopefully, this will make sense to someone.

Comment: Have you considered breaking it down into multiple smaller problems?  Nested "if" statements in excel can get pretty hard to read and debug at times.  Could you do it with a few extra columns containing intermediate results?

Comment: I will take a look at see if I can try this.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=IF(AND(A2>=75%,B2>=10%,C2>=65%),"G",IF(AND(A2>=65%,A2<75%,B2>=5%,B2<10%,C2>=55%,C2<65%),"S",IF(AND(A2>=60%,A2<65%,B2>=3%,B2<5%,C2>=50%,C2<55%),"B","Other")))
```

A change in the layout may help show how very close you were to the answer:

```
=IF(  
AND(A2>=75%,B2>=10%,C2>=65%),"G",  
IF(  
AND(A2>=65%,A2<75%,B2>=5%,B2<10%,C2>=55%,C2<65%),"S",  
IF(  
AND(A2>=60%,A2<65%,B2>=3%,B2<5%,C2>=50%,C2<55%),"B",  
"Other")))
```